# Jquery previous object selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, selector

I have an issue about prev object on jquery it doesnt give me position ... 
I have divs with ".post-image"

```
$(".post-image").each(function(){
    var div = $(this);
    var index = div.index();
    var odd = index % 2;
    if(odd == 1){
        var sibling = div.next();
        sibling.css({
            margin:"15px",
            marginTop:"-165px"
        })
        var bElement= div.prev(".post-image");
        console.log(bElement)
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-header"></div>
    <div class="post-content"></div>
</div>
<div class="post-image">
    <div class="post-header"></div>
    <div class="post-content"></div>
</div>
```

I cant select prev as an object

Comment: What's `patates` ? Post script that has a beginning and ending. And relevant HTML

Comment: Please show associated html and context for your code. Nobody can troubleshoot what they can't see

Comment: Patates - right next to the Tapas object

Comment: Pls add your html containing those elements you're referring in your script

Comment: it was random name I define ı changed and theres more of those htmls like that

Comment: You're iterating over `post-image` elements and there's only one, calling `prev('.post-image')` will try to select another sibling right before this element but there's none as per your HTML

Comment: there are more divs like those <div class="post"></div> and  <div class="post-image"></div> ı want to select prev first element has post-image

Comment: What is expected result of `var bElement= div.prev(".post-image").val();` ? See http://api.jquery.com/val/ "The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`"

Comment: yup.. if you want to see what's inside your element log the element directly or use `html()` not `val()` as it's for form elements

Comment: ı want to select prev div as an object ı need position property of it

Comment: @UğurOruc Does `html` contain more than one element having `post-image` class ?

Comment: yes  I have post and post-images so much i have to select previous one not others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the jQuery docs:

> `.prev( [selector ] )` Get the **immediately** preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Your `<div class="post-image">` element has no **immediately** preceding element with the same class. The element preceding it is `<div class="post">`

**[EDIT]**
You can go this way:

```
// declare bElement variable:
var bElement;
$(".post-image").each(function(){
    var div = $(this);
    var index = div.index();
    var odd = index % 2;
    if(odd == 1){
        var sibling = div.next();
        sibling.css({
            margin:"15px",
            marginTop:"-165px"
        });
        // make sure that previous element with class '.post-image' exists :
        if(bElement !== undefined){
            var prevElemPosition = bElement.position().top;
            // do something ...
        }
    }
    // set latest .post-image element (so that it will be the previous on next iteration):
    bElement = div; 

});
```

Comment: @UğurOruc , then you could use something like in my EDIT.

Comment: bElement gives me object ( [prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: div#4.post-image, jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function, selector: ""…] ) but it doesnt give me position ... it says "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined".. thanks for helping

Comment: @UğurOruc , then you're doing something wrong (or you didn't show enough relevant code to let us diagnose your issue). It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x1szubuo/